# Stancl\Tenancy\Exceptions\NotASubdomainException Hostname DOMAIN.COM does not include a subdomain

Tags: laravel, amazon-ec2, laravel-forge

I am using Laravel Forge with AWS EC2 Instance to build a CI/CD Pipeline for a SAAS Laravel project.

Error Attachment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hsMdK.png

The configurations are fine but when it comes to a tenancy-based project I get this error.
(Stancl\Tenancy\Exceptions\NotASubdomainException
Hostname domain.com does not include a subdomain)

Note: I am using TenancyForLaravel package

Answer (score 0):

I got it fixed in 2 steps.
It wasn't a server-side issue.

**1st Step**

The TenancyForLaravel package was making an impact, I need to add initializing code for sub-domains in my laravel project.

app/Providers/TenancyServiceProvider.php

public function boot() {

```
\Stancl\Tenancy\Middleware\InitializeTenancyBySubdomain::$onFail = 
    function () {
        return redirect(env('CENTRAL_DOMAIN'));
    };
```

}

**2nd Step**

In your laravel root folder

/config/tenancy.php

add your domain name in central_domain

'central_domains' => [
'127.0.0.1',
'localhost',
'domain.com',
],

Answer (score 0):

I was also receiving this error when using the `InitializeTenancyyDomainOrSubdomain` middleware to identify tenants.  Tenants were identified correctly, but the central domain routes did not work with the `NotASubdomainException` being thrown.

I was able to fix this by catching this specific exception in my TenancyServiceProvider.

**/App/Providers/TenancyServiceProvider**

```
public function boot()
    {
        //...

        Middleware\InitializeTenancyBySubdomain::$onFail = function($e, $request, $next){
            if($e::class === 'Stancl\Tenancy\Exceptions\NotASubdomainException' && in_array($request->getHost(), config('tenancy.central_domains'))){
                return $next($request);
            }

            throw $e;
        };

    }
```